# Please discuss meaning of Spirit in 1 Peter 1:11

Tags: translation-philosophy

What are the possible renderings of ‘Spirit of Christ” in 1 Peter 1:11 -

> (BLB) inquiring into what or what manner of time the **Spirit of Christ**
> in them was signifying, testifying beforehand of the sufferings of
> Christ and the glories after these,

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think what I wanted was an exegesis of the verse, ie what variations in renderings were permissible from the Greek text.

Comment: That is quite different from what your question asks.  A standard exegesis of the text can be found in numerous readily available commentaries such as here >> https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_peter/1-11.htm  I have attempted to answer the specific question you asked.

Answer (score 2):

The term is also used by Paul; "Anyone who does not have the Spirit of Christ does not belong to him" (Romans ch8v9, RSV). And this appears to be another way of describing the "Spirit of God" who "dwells in you" in the previous sentence.

But in your quotation from 1 Peter, it is the prophets of the Old Testament who have "the Spirit of Christ within them"; I guess that was the point which drew your attention to the verse.

I would do what Paul appears to do and identify the "Spirit of Christ" with the "Spirit of God". Then I would find my explanation of the double label in the Last Supper discourse in John's gospel. The Spirit belongs to the Father, says Jesus, because the Father will send him "in my name" (John ch14 v26). Yet at the same time the Spirit also belongs to Jesus, because "I will send him" (John ch16 v7).

That is part of the reason why the Nicene Creed (in the western church's version, anyway), says that the holy Spirit proceeds from the Father "and from the Son".

In short, I believe the "Spirit of Christ" to be the Holy Spirit, inspiring the prophets to speak of Christ just as he would inspire the disciples of Jesus to do the same (John ch16 v13)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, "Spirit of Christ", or, "Spirit of Jesus", occurs four times in the NT as follows:

- Acts 16:6, 7 - After **the Holy Spirit** had prevented them from speaking the word in the province of Asia, they traveled through the region of Phrygia and Galatia. And having come down to Mysia, they were attempting to go into Bithynia, and **the Spirit of Jesus** did not allow them.
- Rom 8:9 - Now you are not in flesh but in Spirit, if indeed **the Spirit of God** dwells in you; but if anyone does not have **the Spirit of Christ**, he is not of Him.
- Phil 1:19 - for I know that through your prayer and the provision of **the Spirit of Jesus Christ**, this will turn out for me to deliverance,
- 1 Peter 1:11 - inquiring into what or what manner of time **the Spirit of Christ** in them was signifying, testifying beforehand of the sufferings of Christ and the glories after these,

From this list we deduce several things about "The Spirit of Christ/Jesus":

- The Spirit of Christ is the same as "The Spirit of God" and the "Holy Spirit", as per Acts 16:6, 7, Rom 8:9, 14, 15:19, 1 Cor 2:11, 3:16, 12:3, Eph 4:30, 1 Peter 4:14, Matt 12:28, 1 John 4:2, etc.  In Eph 4:30 we also learn that this is the Holy Spirit.
- It is the Spirit of Christ/God that guided the prophets and apostles.  Compare 2 Peter 1:21.
- It is the Spirit of Christ that teaches Christians about Christ and what actually makes them "Christian"; compare John 16:13, Rom 8:9, etc.
- The Spirit of Christ dwells in us, 1 Peter 1:11, 1 Cor 3:16, 17, 6:19, 20, etc.